# Visual Studio Code, how to switch from powershell.exe to cmd.exe

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to switch from powershell.exe to cmd.exe in the terminal, but how can I do so?

I provided a screenshot for clarification.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: what's the problem? You want to switch the _default_ terminal profile? From the screenshot, it's obvious you know how to change the _current_ profile. But that's what it seems like you're asking how to do from the rest of what you've written.

Answer (score 238):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to show all commands.
2. Type *profile* in the displayed text box to filter the list.
3. Select *Terminal: Select Default Profile*.
4. You will be prompted to *Select your preferred terminal shell, you can change this later in your settings or follow the same process as we do now*
5. Select *Command Prompt* (cmd.exe)
6. Click the Delete Icon in the shell pane to remove the existing terminal.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `` ` `` (or menu *View* → *Terminal* in menu) to open a new terminal pane.

Comment: To take effect, requires VS Code to be shut down and relaunched on Windows 10.

Comment: @Sabuncu Right. Also you can click on + button to add new terminal. After adding you can select cmd from drop down.

Comment: In VSCode 1.55.2, I could not find an option called "Terminal: Select Default Shell". However, I did find "Terminal: Select Default Profile" which seems to do the same thing.

Comment: When I try to debug (using F5) it still uses PowerShell, any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: @JoginderMalik My company's security suite blocks PS, which was the default, and the terminal panel disappears almost immediately after it opens. So there was not enough time to click the + drop down. This fixed it.

Answer (score 22):

2021 Update:

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Type/Paste: **Terminal: Select Default Profile**

[image: Visual Studio Code Settings]

Select the command prompt from the drop down list.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Add this user setting to your menu *File* → *Preferences* → *User Settings*

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",

}
```

Comment: For me, this is was the solution `{"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"}`

Comment: This setting is deprecated ([circa version 1.57](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_terminal-profile-improvements)) see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles.

Answer (score 15):

I found two different ways to switch from PowerShell to the command prompt in Visual Studio Code.

The very simple steps I found myself are as below:

**The first one is also simple and handy for all developers.**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to show all commands.
2. Type `shell` in the displayed text box to filter the list.
3. Select *Terminal: Select Default Shell*.
4. You will be prompted to *Select your preferred terminal shell. You can change this later in your settings or follow the same process as we do now*
5. Select *Command Prompt* (cmd.exe)
6. Click the Delete Icon in the shell pane to remove the existing terminal.
7. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `` ` `` (or menu *View* → *Terminal in menu*) to open a new terminal pane.

---

**The second one is a very simple way:**

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (or menu *View* → *Terminal in menu*) to open a
   new terminal pane.
2. Click terminal selection dropdown and click 'Select Default Shell'.

   [image]
3. Choose the terminal type *Command Prompt* or *PowerShell*

   [image]
4. Now *delete* the current opened terminal or open a new terminal.

Now, Command Prompt will be your default shell in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I initially missed that drop down list that appears below the menu. If you click anywhere it will disappear. But this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Open settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><comma></kbd>)

Find **terminal.integrated.shell.windows**

Replace its value with **`C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe`**.

Comment: This setting is deprecated ([circa version 1.57](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_terminal-profile-improvements))

Answer (score 3):

In the current terminal, simply type <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. And you are done.

Comment: Only on a Mac, presumably?

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem when I clicked on the terminal. It was showing PowerShell, but not Command Prompt, so I did the following steps to get Command Prompt in Visual Studio:

1. Menu *View* → *Command palette* → *Toggle Integrated Terminal*
2. Open terminal by shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>
   or menu *View* → *Terminal*
3. Write the command as `cmd.exe` and run

Answer (score 0):

From Visual Studio if you have PowerShell set as your default integrated terminal, after you call it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (control + backtick) - that toggles from the terminal to your files panel and back. Call the terminal, It will show as 1: pwsh in the dropdown box. From the PowerShell command line type bash and enter. You have your bash prompt $. In the dropdown you now see *1: Bash*.

You can type cmd from either the `ps C:` or the `$` Bash prompt and open the Windows command prompt. C:> and exit to exit them.

You can open up multiple terminals. Say PowerShell (`pwsh`) is your default one. A new terminal will show as `2: pwsh` which you can change to a cmd one. The same if you open a third. Change it to Bash. You now have three terminals `1: pwsh`, `2: cmd`, and `3: bash`. You can select whichever one you want to work with from the dropdown. You can of course exit any of them.

No doubt you've seen that when you are running [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), the terminal becomes node.