# VS Code Python Timeout waiting for debugger connection

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

Yesterday, before Visual Studio Code updated itself (from 1.27.2 to 1.28.2), I could open it from an anaconda prompt after activating a certain environment and debug a script.  Now when I try to debug a script, I get an error about a Timeout waiting for debugger connection.

I've followed some advice on another thread ([Visual Studio Code Python Timeout waiting for debugger connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462599/visual-studio-code-python-timeout-waiting-for-debugger-connection)) and can get it to work if I use the configuration below, but it still seems to be a problem that it won't run in an integrated terminal anymore.

This used to work but breaks now:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

This works now if I want to run in debugger console.

```
{
    "name": "Python: Debug",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "console": "none"
},
```

Comment: Nevermind, seems like this was a bug that was fixed promptly.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and to fix that I added following line to the `settings.json` file:

```
{
    // to fix 'Timeout waiting for debugger connections'
    "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false
}
```