# timeout error when using external terminal in Manjaro

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, kde-plasma, manjaro

I have installed Visual Studio Code with the Python extension in Linux Manjaro. When I try to launch a Python script, the external terminal opens but after 5s I get an error message in a window telling me "timeout" and my script doesn't launch.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462599/visual-studio-code-python-timeout-waiting-for-debugger-connection) post with the same problem on Windows 10 but the fix doesn't seem to work on Manjaro. Any idea?

Here is my launch.json file

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5678,
        "host": "localhost",
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "enter-your-module-name-here",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Django",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/IA_TD2.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "args": [
            "runserver",
            "--noreload",
            "--nothreading"
        ],
        "django": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "flask",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "app.py"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--no-debugger",
            "--no-reload"
        ],
        "jinja": true
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (External Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    },
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (None)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "none"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Could you please show the entries in your `launch.json`? Maybe you want to try switching `"console"` to `"integratedTerminal"` or to `"none"`.  What's the default terminal you're using in Manjaro?

Comment: The integrated terminal works fine but I prefer running in an external one. I tried with xterm and with konsole. They both produce the same error.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2712). Seems that vscode isn't compatible with every terminal. Which desktop environment are you using? I'm using Gnome and debugging with external terminal works fine.

Comment: I am using KDE. Thank you very much for your answers. I guess I have to try other terminals then. Do you have any recommendation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately VSCode is not compatible with every terminal and it seems not (yet) compatible with your **Linux Manjaro** installation with **KDE Desktop Environment**.

Switching to another terminal will surely solve this (i.e. GNOME Terminal). I'm not sure, if the `gnome-terminal` package is aviable without installing the **GNOME Desktop Environment**.

[Here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-desktop-on-manjaro-18-linux) is a good solution how you can do this without reinstalling the whole OS.

Comment: I installed gnome-terminal from the extra repository of manjaro and it works great, no need to change desktop environment. Thanks for solving the problem.