# Python Visual Code Studio Timing out waiting for debugger connection

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0eAP.jpg)I am trying use python on visual studio code. Just try to run some basic hello world program, but its giving me `no connection message`. Error message is `"Timing out waiting for debugger connection"`. It sounds a bit silly , forgive me I am very new and also on console the error message comes as `"ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"`
     I have tried stack overflow , Youtube to see the answers with the tag line, but nothing works. If someone can help to sort out the issue.
This is my json.launch file

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBieA.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nztvC.jpg)

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide the launch.json file?

Comment: Thanks Gabriel C the images of my launch.json files are attached with the file.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you noted the following similar question?**

> [Visual Studio Code Python Timeout waiting for debugger connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462599/visual-studio-code-python-timeout-waiting-for-debugger-connection)

Might be a bit of a different situation but it appears similar to what you've described.