# "Timed out waiting for debuggee to spawn" error for certain conda envs on vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Update:

I just discovered that with a python 3.7 environment created with `Anaconda` (version number 4.11.0, which creates a python 3.7.11), this problem happens while python 3.8(.12) created by conda doesn't have this kind of problem.

And I found a solution: I use `integratedTerminal` in the launch.json, and without specifying terminal type, the default integrated terminal would be `PowerShell` which has this problem. After I change the `terminal.integrated.shell.Windows` setting to cmd.exe, this porlbem goes away and the problem goes through.

Original post:

I am developing a python 3.7 application on `vs-code` on Windows. I am using Anaconda to manage my working environments (and I have created several evns on the same dev machine). The env I am using for this app is called `basic_env` which is of version 3.7.10. Previously it was working fine. But today, when I returned from my 10-day holiday, and after I upgraded the vscode (to `1.64.0`) and probably the python extension (version `v2022.0.1786462952`). The launching/debugging stopped working: a window popped up with an error mesage `Timed out waiting for debuggee to spawn` . I made a simple test python script using the same conda env. My script is only one line

```
print("test....")
```

And my launch.json looks like this:

```
{
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "env": {
            "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
    },
```

The same error showed up.

I tried to google this issue, at first I thought [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/issues/1930) was the same as my problem: using venv caused this problem, and using the system-global python didn't have this problem. So maybe the bug which was fixed 2 years ago was back along with the updates? But then I tried some other conda envs, some worked and some didn't (but none of them was of version 3.7.10). I tried to upgrade this env to 3.7.11 by:

```
conda activate basic_env
conda install python=3.7.11
```

(other existing 3.7.11 envs work fine) but the problem was still there. Also, I don't know how to get the ptvsd.adapter log file in the mentioned post. Could anyone help me track this problem?

Thank you very much!

Cheers

Comment: I have the same issue.  I notice there is a solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462599/visual-studio-code-python-timeout-waiting-for-debugger-connection) but none of those worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Upon reading this post I tried changing my conda env.  I might have changed it a few times and tried to debug.  Eventually 1 just worked.  I thought maybe it was a python version, so I switched to a conda env which just a few seconds earlier hadn't worked with debugging.  But this time it just worked.

I don't have an explanation as to why this worked, but if you're reading this maybe you can just try changing conda env a few times.

Update: I ran into the issue again.  This time toggling conda env didn't seem to work.  I did try to **Run Without Debugging** (which worked), and then I tried **Start Debugging** which to my surprise worked.  Again, no answer to why, but trying to provide info which could help someone.