# Can´t run python files anymore Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Out of the blue VSCode stopped running my python files. When I try to run it the python terminal opens but nothing happens. When I try to debug it says "timed out waiting for launcher to connect".
Has anyone a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code Python Timeout waiting for debugger connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462599/visual-studio-code-python-timeout-waiting-for-debugger-connection)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462599/visual-studio-code-python-timeout-waiting-for-debugger-connection) worked for me:

Changing your "integratedTerminal" shell to cmd.exe will fix it, because it's using "PowerShell".

Open a new terminal pane : Press Ctrl+` (or View > Terminal in menu)
Open a "Command Prompt" Open a "Command Prompt"
Switch "cmd" to default (DO NOT switch to PowerShell)
Switch to default profile