# Can't debug anything in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

VS Code worked perfectly - until now. Nothing changed. Which is why I don't understand why this is happening.

When I try to run and debug a Python file as simple as `Print("Hello")`, it just says:

> Timed out waiting for launcher to connect

which makes no sense at all. No additional information is given. Nothing in the terminal just a random pop-up.

I searched on google and tried a lot of different things. I just don't understand why it doesn't work anymore. I tried reinstalling VS Code, updating Python to the latest version, restarting my PC, updating Windows. Running a simple print in the Python IDE worked - running the same script I made in VS Code using cmd - that also worked.

So this just looks like a VS Code problem. Whenever I hit Open `launch.json` it just asks me in what workspace I want to open it in. Which usually I didn't need to have when just creating a single Python file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code Python Timeout waiting for debugger connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462599/visual-studio-code-python-timeout-waiting-for-debugger-connection)

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed!
The problem was that compatibility mode was enabled. After i unchecked that, it all worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).