# problems with node en vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-modules

I have a very strange problem with node. When I open a folder in my vscode, node does not recognize me but without opening a folder it recognizes it perfectly, I do not understand what the error may be. On the other hand I already have node added to the path.

[image]

Without opening a folder just opening the vscode

[image]

In cmd

[image]

Path
[image]

I don't understand why node doesn't grab me when I open a folder in vscode.

Comment: You probably want to raise this over on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues because that sounds like a bug description, not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Ok,If you know the reason for this error, tell me. Thank you. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132349

Comment: Could this be related to the powershell that you're using? Try using a different terminal.

Comment: So... When i open the terminal in vscode , this program open powershell for default.

Comment: I found a solution but I don't think this is what it should be. Install wsl and install node. And from wsl I ran node in vscode and that worked but I would not believe that this should be a solution.

Comment: Instead, just use cmd instead of powershell. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43751743/740553 (and as a bonus, now you have a shell that supports `&` again, like every other normal shell). No need for WSL here.

Comment: That option I did not know, too interesting. Thank you