# While installing npm package into visual studio code problem

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, executionpolicy

I have used the command to install npm package into my visual studio code for that, fire a command into my terminal,
npm install -g create-react-app
but, I am getting errors.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7wno.png)

Comment: Have you installed **nodejs** ?? run `npx create-react-app .` in terminal

Answer (score 1):

It's basically saying that Powershell's execution policy does not allow running .ps1 scripts. When you run npm install, it tries to execute [image: ``]

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Use command prompt instead of Powershell
2. Set script execution policy in Powershell

## Solution 1

I suggest you take a look at this answer for switching from powershell to command prompt: [Visual Studio Code, how to switch from powershell.exe to cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729130/visual-studio-code-how-to-switch-from-powershell-exe-to-cmd-exe)

## Solution 2

Open powershell as administrator, then type the following command in there
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

This will set the execution policy and allow executing remotely signed (third party) scripts, which means NPM can be run.